# spring data repository query included collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm having an issue performing a custom query through the use of a spring data jpa repository.

I have a repository class implementing JPARepository<>. Everything works as expected for all of the built-in CRUD queries along with some custom queries, but doing qualification among inner collections isn't working and is returning back a full result set as though the qualification of the collection did not exist.

For example, here is a query:

```
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Integer> {
@Query("SELECT a FROM Message a, Message_Topic b WHERE a.systemNm = :theSystem AND a. applicationNm = :theApplication AND b.topicNm = :theTopicName AND a.insertTs BETWEEN :theStartDate AND :theEndDate AND a.expirationDt > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
List<Message> findMessagesByTopic(@Param("theSystem") String theSystem,
        @Param("theApplication") String theApplication,
        @Param("theTopicName") String theTopicName,
        @Param("theStartDate") Date theStartDate,
        @Param("theEndDate") Date theEndDate);
```

With the following JPA entities:

Message:

```
@Entity
public class Message implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="message_id")
private int messageId;

@Column(name="application_nm")
private String applicationNm;

@Column(name="execution_instance_txt")
private String executionInstanceTxt;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="expiration_dt")
private Date expirationDt;

@Column(name="grouping_des")
private String groupingDes;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="insert_ts")
private Date insertTs;

@Column(name="message_detail_txt")
private String messageDetailTxt;

@Column(name="message_summary_txt")
private String messageSummaryTxt;

@Column(name="severity_des")
private String severityDes;

@Column(name="system_nm")
private String systemNm;

//uni-directional many-to-one association to Message_Topic
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="message_id", referencedColumnName="message_id")
private Set<Message_Topic> messageTopics;
```

Message_Topic:

```
@Entity
public class Message_Topic implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="message_topic_id")
private int messageTopicId;

@Column(name="message_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private int messageId;

@Column(name="topic_nm")
private String topicNm;

@Column(name="topic_value_txt")
private String topicValueTxt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT a FROM Message a, Message_Topic b WHERE a.systemNm = :theSystem AND a. applicationNm = :theApplication AND b.topicNm = :theTopicName AND a.insertTs BETWEEN :theStartDate AND :theEndDate AND a.expirationDt > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Where are Message and Message_Topic joined?, If you transform this query to a native query, is possible you can detect the fault.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my stupid... Some days are better than others.